# Add Mesh to Forge Viewer Scene

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I use Forge Viewer v7.12. and I can't add THREE.Mesh to viewer scene. This is not function from version 7.3. How can I add custom geometry (Box, Surface, Line) to Scene?
And console writes this error: .WebGL-0x7f884f0a5400]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: buffer format and fragment output variable type incompatible.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended approach is to use an **overlay** instead of scene or sceneAfter, like this...

```
var geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 8, 8);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
sphereMesh.position.set(1, 2, 3);

viewer.overlays.addMesh(sphereMesh, 'custom-scene');
```

For more details, follow the example here:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/custom-geometry/

Comment: Thank you so much Michael, I was blind :-). Now it's working good.

Comment: how to add new THREE.LineBasicMaterial?