# Set Material of objects on client side

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is it possible to set a custom material on objects when the viewable loads? We are returning a viewable from Design Automation and would like to change the material with a local one, on some of the viewable parts that are returned.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, do you mean load custom material in forge viewer?

Comment: @varunpatil i am trying to set a custom material/texture in the viewer. I need to be able to search for dbIds by the "parent name" and not the component name which is coming back as "Solid 1". is that possible?

Comment: sorry for late reply, i think this question is asked several times on SO, can you please try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60228256/add-mesh-to-forge-viewer-scene